# Selenium Webdriver Xpath: Find and compare the text of an element then click the link that's 4 rows after

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table, xpath-2.0

I want to find and compare the heading in the table. Then click on the delete button that in the next 3 rows of the heading.

Example: Lets say a given input is Heading 2. I want to search Heading 2 and see if it exists then click on the delete button that is associated with 'Heading 2' (like 3-4 rows after).

So far this is the code that i came close to. The only problem is that it always click the first selection instead of where i want it to go.

> String HeadingName = "Heading 2"
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(.,'" + HeadingName + "')]/tr[position()=4]/td[2]/div/a[2]")).click();

This is what the table and it's code looks like.

Heading 1
Name:        Joe
Gender:      Male
Options:     Update | Delete
Heading 2
Name:        Jenny
Gender:      Female
Options:     Update | Delete

```
 <table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
       <th class="st-head-row" colspan="2">Heading 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
      <td class="st-key">Name:</td>
      <td class="st-val">Joe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
      <td class="st-key">Gender:</td>
      <td class="st-val">Male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even last-row">
      <td class="st-key">Options:</td>
      <td class="st-val">
           <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <a id="save" href="linkaddress">save</a>
                | 
                <a id="delete" href="linkaddress">delete</a>
           </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <th class="st-head-row" colspan="2">Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
      <td class="st-key">Name:</td>
      <td class="st-val">Jenny</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
      <td class="st-key">Gender:</td>
      <td class="st-val">female</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even last-row">
      <td class="st-key">Options:</td>
      <td class="st-val">
           <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <a id="save" href="linkaddress">save</a>
                | 
                <a id="delete" href="linkaddress">delete</a>
           </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Take note that there can be more or less batch of rows (one batch is from Heading to options). a

Answer (score 0):

Try next code with xpath

```
String headingName = "Heading 2";

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[text()='"+ headingName +"']/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[@class='even last-row']/td[@class='st-val']/div/a[@id='delete']")).click();
```

If it works, for detailedinfo how this xpath is created look here - http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, unfortunately this code does not work. I did take a look at the link you have sent and somehow getting a good perception on what to do. I do still need help if you have more ideas regarding the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I missed .click(); at the end of my code.
Can you please share the error you are getting after using it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , hope it will help you.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[contains(text(),'" + HeadingName + "')]//following::tr[3]/td[2]/div/a[2]")).click();
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Juhi, unfortunately I have tried that way and it did not work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd try and keep the XPath a bit more "semantic", e.g.

```
//tr[th = 'Heading 2']/following-sibling::tr[starts-with(td[1], 'Options')][1]//a[. = 'delete']
```

Here I'm looking specifically for the "delete" link in the next "Options" row, rather than something more fragile like "the second link in the next-but-two row".

Answer (score 0):

I actually made an answer that surprisingly worked for me.

> dUtil.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/th[contains(text(),'" + headingName + "')]/../following::tr[3]/td[2]/div/a[2]")).click();

I got every condition I wanted.

1. Searches for the heading that is similar to the given input heading
2. Clicks the link 'Delete' that is 3 rows bellow the searched element
3. Should work even if there are more than one batch of rows (batch meaning from heading to delete)
4. The batch doesn't have to be in order.